# How should I proceed with this inequation?

Tags: quadratics

$$(2x + 1)(3x - 5) - 4x(x-3) + 7 \leq 0$$ (is less or equal than "0", someone help me to edit that part).

Step 1:

$$6x^2 - 10x + 3x - 5 - 4x^2 + 12x + 7 \leq 0$$

Step 2:

$$2x^2 - 19x + 7 \leq 0$$

Step 3:

$$ x = \frac{19 + \sqrt{-(19)^2 - 4(2)(7)}}{2(2)}$$

Step 4:

$$ x_1 = 9.125$$ 
$$ x_2 = 0.375$$

But, how to give a SC answer? There is no intersection for the X1 and X2. So the solution in null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: after expanding we obtain $$2x^2+5x+2<0$$ this can be factorized into
$$(x+2)(2x+1)<0$$

Comment: I've controlled again, and i get a different reduction. See my Step2 please.

Comment: we get $$-10x+3x+12x=15x-10x=5x$$ and $$-5+7=2$$

Comment: You are right. A Mistake from my part. Thanks.